# gspread clear specific cell value

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I want to clear the value of a specific cell. Currently my script runs roughly as follows:

```
cell_list = worksheet.range(1, 1, len(rows), column_length)
for cell in cell_list:
    cell.value = rows[cell.row - 1][cell.col - 1]

worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

I want just overwrite my old Data to save some API calls, therefore I don't use a worksheet.clear() before. Some of the new values could be None, these cells should be cleared then.

My Problem is:
If I have e.g in cell B2 the value "a" and I set now to B2 to the value "None" (cell.value = None) and I update the Worksheet "a" will stay in B2. So it didn't update the cell, the old value stay.

I could set B2 to an empty string, but the problem with that is, that that is not an empty cell, therefore If I want to sort after it (in the Browser) it will list it at the top because it is an empty string and not empty. If I then clear the cell manually in the browser and sort it again, it sorts it how I want to.

[image]

**Updated description:**

I have a cell list that I want to update with new values in my table. It can happen that a cell contains a value before, but the updated cell should not contain a value anymore.

So the old value of A1 is e.g. "5" and the new value for A1 should be nothing.
The problem is, if I assign the value None to the cell in the cell list, the cell will keep the old value after the update. So the value is still "5".

If I pass an empty string into the cell for updating, the new cell is empty, as desired. But now there is the problem that sorting doesn't work properly for me, so this is not an option for me. I could also clear the whole table before, but I try to avoid this to save API calls.

So I'm looking for a way to tell a cell that it does not contain a value

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: yea sure. I added an additional description. Do you need more context or is this fine?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I thought that I could understand about your issue. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is `worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)`. In gspread, it seems that the default value of ValueInputOption is `RAW`. I think that by this, such error occurs. So in order to avoid this, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

#### To:

```
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

- By this modification, I think that `""` which is the empty string can be used for clearing the cells.

#### References:

- [update_cells(cell_list, value_input_option='RAW')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)

Comment: @Nogrod Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand about your situation by your additional information. Thank you, too.